# How to escape predefined symbols e.g. % with plotmath?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotmath

I'm using the `plotmath` support while adding annotations to my plot i.e. using the `parse=TRUE` argument. Reviewing the [plotmath documentation here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html) it is not clear how to escape predefined symbols e.g. %

```
label <- 'atop(This~goes~on~top,of~this~with~11.1%)' # how to escape the % sign?
geom_text(...,label=label,parse=TRUE)
```

which leads to the following error:

```
Error in parse(text = as.character(lab)) : <text>:1:40: unexpected input
1: atop(This~goes~on~top,of~this~with~11.1%)
                                          ^
```

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/980833).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put it in quotes

```
label <- 'atop(This~goes~on~top,of~this~with~"11.1%")'
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point() + 
    annotate("text", x = 4, y = 25, label = label, parse=TRUE)
```

Just put all test in quotes

```
label <- 'atop("This goes on top of this with 11.1%")'
```

Comment: Perfect it works! thank you!